# Airconsole & Unity integration issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, airconsole

First of all i'm new to unity & airconsole both platforms.

I was just exploring unity with airconsole integration but i'm getting errors on importing "airconsole plugin" (imported from `Asset Store`).

I'm using latest version of unity `2018.3.0f2 Personal` on windows 10.

Following are few error messages i can see in unity console

> Assets\AirConsole\plugins\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\DynamicWrapper.cs(27,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ModuleBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\AirConsole\plugins\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\DynamicWrapper.cs(25,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ModuleBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\AirConsole\plugins\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.cs(193,72): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ILGenerator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\AirConsole\plugins\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.cs(214,81): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ILGenerator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> ...........

How can i resolve the issue & test basic airconsole examples.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to update the Newtonsoft.Json Library. Instead, you can simply set `API Compatibility Level` to `.NET 4.x` in `Player Settings / WebGL Settings / Other Settings`.

For this to resolve the errors, the Platform (in Build Settings) needs to be set to `WebGL`, or you have to change the API Compatibility level also for your currently selected Platform in its own `Player Settings`

Comment: It also worked for me after deleting "Assets\AirConsole\plugins\Newtonsoft.Json" folder. Not sure about the reason.

Comment: That is very likely to break the whole plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The last version officially supported by AirConsole is `2018.2.11` (see the asset store [download page](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/systems/airconsole-42776) under "supported versions") , seeing you are running `2018.3.x` this may cause versioning errors.

Importing the asset in Unity `2017.3.0` yielded no errors, so downgrading to the latest officially supported version should do the trick.

If however you want to stick to Unity `2018.3` You'll have to either wait for support from the developers, or you can try updating your Newtonsoft.Json library to the newest verion.

To update you need to download `Newtonsoft.Json` with NuGet using `PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 12.0.1` inside the NuGet package manager, and overwrite the version that is inside Assets\AirConsole\Plugins. [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Updating the Newtonsoft version rid me of the errors you posted above in `2018.3` but i have not tested it thoroughly, so cannot guarantee that it'll work 100%.