# AirConsole for Unity 2018.3.2f.1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, airconsole

After downloading AirConsole from the Unity AssetStore, project generates errors

[image: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/335331093848915968/536464500572815369/unknown.png?width=1156&height=651]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Airconsole & Unity integration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036708/airconsole-unity-integration-issue)

Welcome to stack overflow! Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page on how to ask a proper, answerable question. That said see the above SO post and answer. It is because you are using an unsupported unity version.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by setting `API Compatibility Level` to `.NET 4.x` in `Player Settings / WebGL Settings / Other Settings`.

For this to resolve the errors, the Platform (in Build Settings) needs to be set to `WebGL`, or you have to change the API Compatibility level also for your currently selected Platform in its own `Player Settings`